Polylang assignation id
While i working on my wordpress site, i made a small mistake to duplicate content.
Once page has been assigned to other language content origin in former content ,after copy new content detect former origin as original content.
Which cause issues on travelling languages.
Where i can found assignation id for contents on poly lang (example : en id =6357 tr id=6547)
Regards to all
Update fields assignation on database or polylang settings
Tried to find myself but all failed

you can change the language of a page when you edit it : https://polylang.pro/doc/translating-pages-posts-categories-and-tags/
